# What is the biblical argument that contraception in marriage is acceptable?

Tags: biblical-basis, contraception

The Catholic Church is renowned for its solid stance on codemning the use of artificial contraception.  However, outside of Catholicism, What is the biblical argument that contraception in marriage is acceptable?

Comment: I'm not sure the question is exactly the same, but the basic response is covered [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/305/why-do-protestants-allow-contraception).