# Do Jehovah's Witnesses allow contraception, what forms do they allow, and what are their arguments for it?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, contraception

Questions specifically on the Jehovah's Witnesses faith on contraception:

1. Do Jehovah's Witnesses allow contraception?
2. What forms do they allow?
3. What are their arguments for allowing (or not allowing) contraception?

On question #2 I am mostly curious on what the Bible describes Onan as doing in [Genesis 38:8,9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2038&version=NIV). Is that allowed or not and why?

Genesis 38:8,9:

> Then Judah said to Onan, “Sleep with your brother’s wife and fulfill
> your duty to her as a brother-in-law to raise up offspring for your
> brother.” 9 But Onan knew that the child would not be his; so whenever
> he slept with his brother’s wife, **he spilled his semen on the
> ground** to keep from providing offspring for his brother.

Comment: Related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/305/why-do-protestants-allow-contraception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jehovah's Witnesses allow birth control. Their only stipulation is that it be "non-abortive," presumably meaning not a form that involves destroying an embryo. From [their web site](https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/contraceptives-bible-view/):

> Married couples, therefore, are free to decide for themselves whether
> they will raise a family or not. They may also decide how many
> children they will have and when they will have them. If a husband and
> wife choose to use a nonabortive form of contraception to avoid
> pregnancy, that is their personal decision and responsibility. No one
> should judge them.—Romans 14:4, 10-13.

Onan apparently practiced [coitus interruptus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onan). This in itself is not specified as a sin in the OT,  but the reason he did so was in order to avoid performing his duty to keep his brother's name alive through [levirate marriage.](https://www.britannica.com/topic/levirate)